# How do I open the first file in a folder

Tags: python, opencv

I am unsure how top open and show the first file in a folder. Currently my code is as follows:

```
def listdir_nohidden1(path):
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if not f.startswith('.'):
            yield f

first = sorted(listdir_nohidden1('/Users/harryhat/Desktop/Code/Experimental/dropvibration200fps'))[0]
image_test = cv.imread(first, 0)
cv.imshow('image', image_test)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

The first part of the code is necessary as there are some hidden files which can'[t be red so to avoid this I added that. When I try to run this code an error occurs, the error is attached as an image. The folder just contains images bar the one hidden file. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

[image]

Edit 1:

This is the error I now get, isn't this because listdir does indeed return special characters as well?

[image]

Comment: define 'first file' please - it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Het whole `listdir_nohidden1(path)` method should not be necessary for the standard hidden files `.` and `..`.

*Python method listdir() returns a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. **It does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.***

It does however not excluded other hidden files, like '.DS_store'.

Your problem lies in the fact that `os.listdir()` only gives the filenames, not the path. You should combine path and filename when opening the image.

```
def listdir_nohidden1(path):
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if not f.startswith('.'):
            yield f

pathname = '/Users/harryhat/Desktop/Code/Experimental/dropvibration200fps'
first = sorted(listdir_nohidden1(pathname))[0]
image_test = cv.imread(os.path.join(pathname, first), 0)
cv.imshow('image', image_test)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't realise it only retuned the file name and not the path so thank you for that. In regard to it no returning special entries such as '.' and '..', may be I am misunderstanding but I am still getting an error due to it trying to open '.DS_Store'. The photo is attached.

Comment: Ah, yes. I thought you meant the standard directory entries `.` and `..`. Those are excluded bij `os.listdir()`. To exclude '.DS_Store' you can indeed use your function. I'll edit my answer to include that.